# Why can't I see this aws-sdk function from inside my AWS Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

My goal here is to be able to use the AWS `CloudWatchLogs.startQuery` function from within my AWS Lambda's handler function. This method exists when I run it locally through nodejs, but it's undefined when I run inside my handler. I think I'm doing the same thing in both places, but I get different results. For comparison, I can see the `filterLogEvents` method in both places, as I expected. Both methods are documented in the [AWS javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html). Why can't I see this function inside my lambda?

My nodejs code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./aws_credentials.json');
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    apiVersion: '2014-03-28'
});

var cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs();
var filterlogevents_type = typeof cloudwatchlogs.filterLogEvents;
var startquery_type = typeof cloudwatchlogs.startQuery;

console.log(startquery_type);      // function 
console.log(filterlogevents_type); // function
```

From within my lambda's index.js file:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    apiVersion: '2014-03-28'
});
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs();
    var filterlogevents_type = typeof cloudwatchlogs.filterLogEvents;
    var startquery_type = typeof cloudwatchlogs.startQuery;

    const response = {
        body: JSON.stringify({
            startQuery: startquery_type,           // undefined
            filterLogEvents: filterlogevents_type  // function
        }),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of wiring, Lambda includes [version 2.290.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) of the AWS SDK in the runtime, which is from [August 2018](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/releases/tag/v2.290.0). However, StartQuery was [only released in November 2018](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/announcing-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-fast-interactive-log-analytics/) and appeared in the [version 2.364.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/7b4bea109087da7dd1696cde4c153bbd53a30da9/.changes/2.364.0.json) of the SDK. The workaround is to package the latest version of the SDK yourself instead of relying on the included library.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the insight and the workaround!  In the API docs alone it's not obvious which functions were available in which versions.